# Resize from Center [Winforms]

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, window-resize

i have 2 forms (parent & child)
child form's properties are `ControlBox:False`, `DoubleBuffer:True` & `FormBorderStyle:SizeableToolWindow` (rest all are default values).
 i want child form to resize from center (and not from top left)

In Child form `Resize` Event, i have following code

```
this.Location = System.Drawing.Point(x / 2 - this.Width / 2, y / 2 - this.Height / 2);
//tried this.CenterToParent();`
```

where x = parent form's width and y = parent form's height.

now after showing child form from parent form, while resizing it flickers a lot, child form tends to go back to its original location! 
 how to create smooth resize from center?
is there a way to change Form's resize origin to center? 

this question is already posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f35bca39-9352-411e-b084-7b611ca08479/changing-form-position-after-resizing?forum=winforms), but didn't understand solution

Comment: That solution already gives all you need, if you don't understand it you will not understand any solution posted here as will be the same.

Comment: You found the solution. This is the heart of the issue: override the WinProc for that window and then 'eat' that SDK message.

Comment: @Dysmondad, Thanks for you reply. i'm new to C# and winform. so i don't know what is WinProc, how to handle SDK message e.t.c

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Location.X / 2 - this.Width / 2, this.Location.Y / 2 - this.Height / 2);
            //tried this.CenterToParent();`
            base.OnResize(e);
        }

        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
        const int SC_MAXIMIZE2 = 0xF032;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if ((m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && m.WParam == new IntPtr(SC_MAXIMIZE)) || m.WParam == new IntPtr(SC_MAXIMIZE2))
            {
                this.Size = this.MaximumSize;
                m.Result = new IntPtr(0);
                //base.WndProc(ref m);
                //Eat the message so won't process further
            }
            else
            {
                m.Result = new IntPtr(0);
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the better link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer & reference link. i tried your code. for some reason while resizing, form still flash at old location!

Comment: @Prakash M, This is just to show how to add the override. Does this work in your code ?

Comment: it works (resize happens at center) but how to avoid flickering ? can you try on your end?