# Moving a borderless form results in weird side effects

Tags: c#, borderless

I am fairly new to C#. 
In order to get a modern design application, I decided to make my form borderless. I then found a code snippet for making it possible to move my borderless form, which works perfectly fine.

```
private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
            m.Result = (IntPtr)(HT_CAPTION);
            break;
    }
}
```

I also need to fetch the form maximize event, and found another code snippet, which again, works perfectly. At least if I use them independently.

```
                case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                if (IsMaximized == false)
                {
                    IsMaximized = true;
                    Btn_Ribbon_MaximizeMinimize.Image = Properties.Resources.Img_MinimizeForm;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                }
                else if (IsMaximized == true)
                {
                    IsMaximized = false;
                    Btn_Ribbon_MaximizeMinimize.Image = Properties.Resources.Img_MaximizeForm;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                break;
```

Now here comes the weird part. If I use them both together...

```
        #region Move borderless Form
    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HT_CLIENT = 0x1;
    private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_NCHITTEST:
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(HT_CAPTION);
                break;
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                if (IsMaximized == false)
                {
                    IsMaximized = true;
                    Btn_Ribbon_MaximizeMinimize.Image = Properties.Resources.Img_MinimizeForm;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                }
                else if (IsMaximized == true)
                {
                    IsMaximized = false;
                    Btn_Ribbon_MaximizeMinimize.Image = Properties.Resources.Img_MaximizeForm;
                    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

...I get all kind of weird side effects:

- A single click on my form is enought for it to maximize itself
- After minimizing my application, clicking its icon in the windows taskbar again, does not result in it normalizing, but maximizing

How can I get rid of those side effects, or even better than a workaround, is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: @duDE no, it certainly isn't. I don't want to make my borderless form movable, since it is already working as intended. I wanna get rid of the bugs, caused by it.

Answer (score 0):

The `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message can contain information about more than just the maximize event. When you handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` and tell the OS that the caption bar was clicked, it also causes a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` when you release the mouse button.

You should  inspect the `m.WParam` value to determine what action was performed.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) mentions **SC_MAXIMIZE** (0xF030) but on my machine the value is actually **SC_MAXIMIZE2** (0xF032). I can't find any documentation about that value, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43503348/292411) also mentions it.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand#remarks), 4 low-order bits of `wParam` are used internally by the OS. So if you mask them out, that would give you `0xF030`.